# T3-Framework does not load variables.less

Tags: joomla, less, joomla-template

I'm developing a template using T3-framework. I couldn't remember what did I change exactly, but my variables.less does not get loaded. I can see this when I'm inspecting my `<h1>` tag, it shows `font-size: * 2`. It means that the variable before `*` went missing and it weirdly show something like that.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm assuming that I accidentally edit `@import` tag. I've searched the tag and make sure it points to the correct url, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Apparently the file under `t3-assets/dev` folder did not generated properly due to exhaustion in php resources.

It works just fine once I regenerate the files.

Comment: Don't forget to select your answer as the correct answer in case someone else has a similar problem.